# Tutorials for writing a parser with Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I've seen a couple of languages (namely [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) and [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/)) that are built on Javascript.

Are there tutorials anywhere for writing languages/parsers with Javascript?

Comment: CoffeeScript is not based on Node.js ("The core compiler however, does not depend on Node") and it is not DSL.

Comment: http://zaach.github.com/jison/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Jison](https://github.com/zaach/jison) is modeled on the GNU Bison parser generator. It takes a language grammar in Bison-like or JSON format and outputs a Javascript parser for the language. If you're wanting to make an interpreter that's based on on another well-known language, there's probably a Bison grammar around somewhere you can tweak for Jison. 
I've found it very straightforward to get started on a from-scratch DSL.

Answer (score 13):

Why would you think the fundamental concepts of implementing languages "on JavaScript" are fundamentally dependent on JavaScript?  Mostly its just a programming language and standard compiler-like approaches  can be applied; one "merely" compiles to JavaScript instead of machine instructions.

Here's a tutorial on writing compilers using very straightforward metacompiling methods.  It happens to target JavaScript as a starting place, but it isn't committed to JavaScript either.  This tutorial is based on a paper by Val Schorre on "MetaII", a kind of metacompiler .... dated *1964* (yes, you read that right) .  I learned how to build my first compiler from this paper (but not with JavaScript :), and it is still a valuable technique:

[Meta II Compiler Tutorial targeting JavaScript](http://www.bayfronttechnologies.com/mc_tutorial.html)

If you want something more immediate, consider [writing a recursive descent parser by hand.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769).  After you've written a few of these, you'll really appreciate what bit of genius MetaII is.

Comment: Downvoter: Constructive feedback would be preferred instead of your apparant "flag".   I don't see what it is about this response that doesn't directly address OP's request for ways to "build languages" with JavaScript,since that's exactly what the referenced tutorial does.

Comment: I think it's incredibly relevant.  A parser is something that interprets a language to machine-level understanding.  If the OP wants to have any real power over his parser, he is going to need to know how to write a compiler; otherwise, he won't have the independence to take his project very far.  He'll post tutorial request after tutorial request and continue to work with poorly-documented spaghetti code at a slow crawl.  If he writes a compiler, though, he'll be able to write code in his sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at more languages that compile to javascript and see what they do.  Here's a list: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS

See the list of parser generators at the bottom of that page that make things a bit easier, such as jison and peg.js.

There are certain limits or hurdles when writing an alternative language that compiles to javascript, since javascript wasn't designed to be a 'bytecode' or a runtime for other languages.  There are no static types or class system, for example, like in java and C#.  If you're just doing a minor alteration to fix some of javascript's issues like coffeescript and others listed at the top of the page at that link, stuff like that isn't a problem, but then a bigger issue is why not just contribute to coffeescript or similar languages instead.