# Accessing the properties of objects after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I do an ajax call and I get the data back from the controller in this form.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [cat_id] => 2
        [title] => Clothes
        [description] => Clothing for men and women
        [active_coupon_counter] => 0
        [store_id] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [cat_id] => 17
        [title] => Designer
        [description] => ;description
        [active_coupon_counter] => 0
        [store_id] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [cat_id] => 24
        [title] => Fashion
        [description] => ;description
        [active_coupon_counter] => 0
        [store_id] => 1
    )

)
Array
```

This might seem foolish, but I cannot figure out how on earth would I access the `cat_id` and `title` properties in each of the arrays!

Any help, guys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use object notation for accessing them:

```
array[0].cat_id
// returns 2
```

**UPDATE**

The returned format from your server has to be `JSON`, it should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "cat_id": 2,
        "title": "Clothes",
        "description": "Clothing for men and women",
        "active_coupon_counter": 0,
        "store_id": 1
    },
    {
        "cat_id": 17,
        "title": "Designer",
        "description": ";description",
        "active_coupon_counter": 0,
        "store_id": 1
    },
    {
        "cat_id": 24,
        "title": "Fashion",
        "description": ";description",
        "active_coupon_counter": 0,
        "store_id": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: can you show us your actual program? how does your returned data look

Comment: This is how it looks like. I did an 'alert' and this showed up.

Comment: then that is what the string contains, javascript will not understand that format, you will have to change it to valid JSON

Comment: explain the down vote please, really irritating when someone down-votes with no apparent reason.

Comment: Also! I did json_encode and I am getting the data back in JSON format. Thanks. :)

Comment: sorry, it was not directed at you, but rather who-ever did :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be getting a PHP var_dump or print_r of the data. This is not something that is convenient to parse.

I'm not aware of any JavaScript parser for the format, so you might have to write one from scratch. The question [Tutorials for writing a parser with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874609/tutorials-for-writing-a-parser-with-javascript) should give you guidance on that subject.

You would be better off editing the server side script to return the data in a more reasonable format such as JSON or XML.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are using JSON to send and receive data.

So you can access the array object and use:

```
yourArrayObject[indexYouWantToAccess].cat_id
```

Comment: "It seems like you are using JSON to send and receive data." — The data in the question looks nothing like JSON!

Comment: Can you put the code where you receive your data on js from the controller?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using `mysql_fetch_object` to get data from the database? Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_array`.

Also, the response doesn't seem to be a valid json response, as `json_encode` works properly on both `mysql_fetch_object` and `mysql_fetch_assoc/array`.